# Mobile Broadband is not working

Tags: networking, 14.04, mobile-broadband

This seems to be a huge problem! In my network dropdown menu there are so many items such as the image shown below, all of them are not been used by me any time since the first session of ubuntu after the installation. I can't connect to a mobile boradband connection with this issue. Even it doesn't recognize my HSDPA modem.

[image]

This was the error that given by the connection manager when i tried to create a new network or click any item that drop down lish shows.

`"(32) The connection was not supported by oForno."`

I removed oFoto so i thought i could solve my problem unluckily i couldn't.

## I have another ubuntu os installed in my pc as im dual booting those two os togethor. I use other os as my default and i used to connect internet from every single method that drop down list shows.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running 14/04 (Trusty) version of Ubuntu? I was experiencing a similar problem when I upgraded my laptop to 14.04. My AT&T/Sierra 313 broadband modem, which has worked under all previous versions of Ubuntu, would no longer work and the Mobile Broadband option would not work either

I determined that the problem seems to be with new version of the "Modem manager" package installed with 14.04. I was able to fix the problem by downgrading just the one package to the version from 12.04 (Precise) since this version is still supported and available. The steps I took are documented in the answer I posted to my own question, here:

[Sierra Wireless 313u 3G broadband modem will not work since upgrade to 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/491841/sierra-wireless-313u-3g-broadband-modem-will-not-work-since-upgrade-to-14-04#)