# Sierra Wireless 313u 3G broadband modem will not work since upgrade to 14.04

Tags: wireless, networking, 14.04, mobile-broadband

I recently upgraded my Toshiba Portege laptop to 14.04. Since doing so, I cannot get my Sierra Wireless Air Card 313u to connect. Since this unit worked fine in the previous LTS version, I believe the issue is either with 14.04 or with my upgrade.

Previously, I would use this usb air card as follows:

1. Prior to plugging in the aircard, in the past version, there would be no "Enable Mobile Broadband" option in the networking drop down menu.
2. When the air card is plugged in, after it boots and there is a blinking green light on the dongle indicating that it is communicating with the network, the "Enable Mobile Broadband" menu item would appear and I would check it. Afer several seconds, a notification would appear on the laptop screen indicating that I am now "registered on the GSM Network."
3. I would then select the "AT&T LaptopConnect (Data Cards) selection on the drop down menu, and I would receive a notice that I was connected to the network through that connection.

Since upgrading to 14.04:

1. I plug in the air card as before. There is an "Enable Mobile Broadband" option on the drop down menu as before. Note that my "AT&T LaptopConnect" connection is also present, and not grayed out as it used to be under the previous version.
2. If I check "Enable Mobile Broadband," after several seconds I get the notification "Mobile Broadband enabled - you are now registered on the home network."
3. If I then click on "AT&T Laptop Connect" the network icon will indicate activity, but then I receive the notice "Modem disconnected"
4. At this point, there is no longer an entry in the drop down menu for the "AT&T Laptop Connect" connection, and the "Mobile Broadband" entry is unchecked again.

I have tried bypassing the step of checking "Enable Mobile Broadband" and going straight to the step of selecting the "AT&T LaptopConnect" connection, and the results are the same.

I have tried building a new connection for the AT&T modem, with the same results when I use it.

I have confirmed that there is an entry for what I believe to be the modem when I query lsusb in a terminal.

I have confirmed that the connection, with a uuid, is present by using the nmcli connection command.

I do not recall having to use any proprietary drivers for this modem, but I'm wondering if perhaps there was a driver that got wiped out during the recent upgrade to 14.04?

From research on this and other forums, there appears to be considerable comment concerning mobile broadband and 14.04. Is there an issue here?

If not, what can I do to be able to use the modem again?

Answer (score 1):

After two weeks of frustrating searching, research and reading, I have managed to repair the problem. The issue appears to be the new version of modem-manager installed on upgrading to Trusty.

Since I knew the modem had worked under previous releases of Ubuntu, I figured if I could downgrade just the one package (modem-manager) I might stand a chance of getting a working Sierra Wireless 313u again. Sure enough, this worked. Here are the steps I took:

1. Install Synaptic, since it allows forced downgrades and locking versions
2. add the repository for Precise Pangolin back into Synaptic sources, since this LTS release of Ubuntu is still supported the the repositories would be easily accessible (also, the modem had worked under Precise).
3. Use Synaptic to force installation of Modem-manager 0.5.2.0-0Ubuntu2, which is the Precise version of the package.
4. Use Synaptic to lock this version in place, and prevent an upgrade to the newer, non-working version of Modem-manager (the new version, in Trusty, is 1.0.0-2Ubuntu1)

As quickly as this was done, the normal functioning and use of the Sierra 313u broadband modem was restored.

Comment: I have the same problem in Ubuntu 17.01 ZESTY... no way to make it work.